# UIElement.AddHandler() vs .Event += Definition

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

**1.st part of the quesion:**
What is the difference between these 2 event registrations ?

```
_popUp.AddHandler(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(PopUp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown));

_popUp.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(_popUp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
```

**2.nd part of the question:**
or eventually versus

```
popUp.Opened += PopUp_Opened;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Redgate's Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), there is no difference. Both methods eventually call the internal method `EventHandlerStore.AddRoutedEventHandler`. This is the reflector output of the `add` accessor for the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event (in the class `UIElement`):

```
public void add_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventHandler value)
{
    this.AddHandler(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, value, false);
}
```

As you can see it calls `UIElement.AddHandler` for you.

Before you edited your question you were asking about the `Opened` event of the popup. In that case, there is a difference: First, the `Opened` event is not implemented as a routed event but as a simple event, so you can't even use the `AddHandler` call on it. Secondly, the reflector shows that a different method is called in the `EventHandlerStore` which adds the handler to a simple delegate collection.

Answer (score 6):

The important thing might be the `AddHandler(xxx,xxx, false)`.

If you use `true` then you can catch events that have already been handled, which can be useful if you subclass Controls like TextBox.