# pass method to event handler in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

This works in adding an event handler in C# WPF

```
CheckBox ifPrint = new CheckBox();
ifPrint.AddHandler(CheckBox.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(
(sender, e) => //toggle check box event
{
    //do stuff
}));
```

but it looks messy when the method body gets long, so I want to define the method elsewhere like this

```
ifPrint.AddHandler(CheckBox.ClickEvent, delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    checkBoxClick(sender, e);
});

private void checkBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//do stuff
}
```

but this doesn't even compile with the error: `Cannot convert anonymous type to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type`

Sorry, I am new to this and have no idea how it's supposed to be done. Is this even close? Thanks!

Comment: You can access the event directly from ifPrint. You can say ifPrint.Click += checkBoxClick;

Comment: @Max thanks, magic! guess i'll study delegate later then...

Comment: A delegate would look like ifPrint.Click += delegate(object s, RoutedEventArgs e){ //doSomething };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to a separate method like this, as long as the signature of `checkBoxClick` is correct:

```
ifPrint.Click += checkBoxClick;
```

You can also subscribe to an event inline like this:

```
ifPrint.Click += (s, e) => SomeMethod();
```

Which then allows you to name your method something more reasonable and not require it to accept parameters:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

---

Just to explain it a little further, in the above code, `s` and `e` take the place of the parameters in your `checkBoxClick` event method, so it's basically equivalent to this:

```
ifPrint.Click += checkBoxClick;

private void checkBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SomeMethod();
}
```

---

*Edit, in regards to your comment.*

> Given this is much simpler, when, if ever, should one use this? `ifPrint.AddHandler(CheckBox.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler( (sender, e) => { //do stuff }));`

I honestly don't think I've ever used that syntax.

It seems that [in most cases it does the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146982/uielement-addhandler-vs-event-definition). According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899(v=vs.110).aspx) docs, there's a `handledEventsToo` parameter on the `AddHandler()` method, which I think could be significant.

Imagine you subscribed to an event multiple times, like this:

```
ifPrint.Click += checkBoxClick;
ifPrint.Click += checkBoxClick;
ifPrint.Click += checkBoxClick;
```

And inside your event, you set `e.Handled = true`. If you didn't have that line, you'd see the message box displayed 3 times. But with that line, you only get the message box once, because the first time the event fires, it marks the event "handled".

```
private void checkBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

By passing in `true` for the last parameter (it's `false` by default), you actually tell it to fire that event, *even if other events already "handled" the event*.

```
ifPrint.AddHandler(CheckBox.ClickEvent,
    new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) => { /* do stuff */ }), true);
```

Comment: thanks! Given this is much simpler, when, if ever, should one use this?  `ifPrint.AddHandler(CheckBox.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(
(sender, e) => {
    //do stuff
}));`

Answer (score 1):

try this logic to attach click event handler for your checkbox.

```
CheckBox ifPrint = new CheckBox();
ifPrint.Click+=checkBoxClick;


private void checkBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//do stuff
}
```