# PointerCaptureLost c# UWP Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I am working on UWP Windows 10 application using C#.
For some animation I was relying on PointerPressed and PointerReleased events. Hoping that these will be fired in pairs. And I was wrong. Check what Microsoft has to say about this: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointercapturelost

Now, I am using PointerCaptureLost in place of PointerReleased and it is working fine. Only problem is if I use AddHandler for PointerCaptureLost it shows an error: "UIElement.PointerCaptureLost can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=". It is only working when added as +=.

Any thoughts why it is like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `UIElement.PointerCaptureLostEvent` with `AddHandler`, because that is the Routed Event ID, which specifies the event. In contrast, `x.PointerCaptureLost` (where `x` is the name of the control) is the field that represents the Event Handler itself.

I had no problem using both `x.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerCaptureLostEvent, ...)` and `x.PointerCaptureLost += ...` in my code. Moreover, as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146982/uielement-addhandler-vs-event-definition) suggests, they both translate to the same 
call to `AddRoutedEventHandler`.